# Winnable AI in tic tac toe

Tags: flutter, algorithm

I was working on a tic tac toe project and used some reference code from a github source.
But the AI seems impossible to beat. But this is not supposed to happen and I can't find ideas to make the AI beatable. Because if I loosen up the game logic the AI will be easy to beat.

My game logic as of now:

```
 Move _getBestMove(List<int> board, int currentPlayer) {
    // try all possible moves
    List<int> newBoard;
    // will contain our next best score
    Move bestMove = Move(score: -10000, move: -1);

    for (int currentMove = 0; currentMove < board.length; currentMove++) {
      if (!TacUtility.isMoveLegal(board, currentMove)) continue;

      // we need a copy of the initial board so we don't pollute our real board
      newBoard = List.from(board);

      // make the move
      newBoard[currentMove] = currentPlayer;

      // solve for the next player
      // what is a good score for the opposite player is opposite of good score for us
      int nextScore =
          -_getBestScore(newBoard, TacUtility.flipPlayer(currentPlayer))!;

      // check if the current move is better than our best found move
      if (nextScore > bestMove.score!) {
        bestMove.score = nextScore;
        bestMove.move = currentMove;
      }
    }

    return bestMove;
  }
}


class Move {
  int? score;
  int? move;
  Move(this.score, this.move);
}
```

Full Code: [AI](https://pastebin.com/wB540NHX) and [Utility](https://pastebin.com/1BUD9vd7)

Since the game is pretty simple on it's own what are some of the logics that can be implemented to "soften" up the difficulty level?

Comment: The idea is that an AI plays well. You seem to want an AI that plays worse than the average human? Just drop the AI, and let the algorithm just play a random move, except when the opponent has a direct threat. Then play the move that prevents it.

Comment: This is not an "AI", it is a plain algorithm. The winning strategy is simplistic.

Comment: This AI looks as far ahead as it needs to to win the game.  You need to limit how far ahead it looks to probably one or two moves (and add some randomization of move-choices too).

Comment: Got it. I just need to look too far ahead or implement some randomized value for the first moves or so...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make a sub-optimal or random move with a certain (adjustable) probability? Preferably not one that makes the opponent win immediately, but you could even play around with that

Comment: There is little room  to make a difference between winning and winning immediately.

Comment: True, there is very little room. It's mostly that the early moves could be more randomized, whereas later moves (where the other is about to win) will likely have to be optimal for the game to be interesting. Mostly it's up to OP how he wants to handle it I guess

Comment: I mean that an "immediately winning" game takes five or six moves (depending on who starts) on a maximum of nine.

Comment: So in short depending on who starts the game I need to randomize maybe the first 1/2 moves by the algorithm and maybe try to implement optimal solution for the later moves?